# Remove whitespace from lighting:card header

Tags: lightning-card

There's quite a bit of space left where title and actions go. Ideally I'd like to remove it.
What are the options here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are referring to the top padding:
[image]

then you can scope your css as follows:

```
.THIS header.slds-card__header.slds-grid{
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

Feel free to modify it as needed.

If you  have other cards, it will affect all of them
If you have some cards that would not need the change in styling, i would suggest adding a custom class to your title and scope accordingly:

```
.THIS.customCardClass > header.slds-card__header.slds-grid{
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

Sample Card:

```
<lightning:card class="customCardClass ">
    <aura:set attribute="title">
        Hello!
    </aura:set>
    <aura:set attribute="footer">
        <lightning:badge label="footer"/>
    </aura:set>
    <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <lightning:button label="New"/>
    </aura:set>
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        Card Body (custom component)
    </p>
</lightning:card>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking for how to do this in LWC and not Aura Components?

Winter 21, Salesforce (beta) released the use of styling hooks : [See how to use them here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_custom_properties)

If you want to completely remove the padding and/or margin that comes from a standard Salesforce LWC Card, try adding this to the CSS File in your LWC bundle:

```
:host {
  /* Removes SF Card Header padding/margin top/bottom only */
  --slds-c-card-header-spacing-block-end: 0px;
  --slds-c-card-header-spacing-block-start: 0px;
  
    /* Removes SF Card body padding/margin top/bottom only */
  --slds-c-card-body-spacing-block-start: 0px;
  --slds-c-card-body-spacing-block-end: 0px;
}
```

Where can you find additional properties, so you can change additional aspects on the SF card?

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/?variant=wrapper#Styling-Hooks-Overview

Hope this is helpful for all you LWC devs out there.